# Process rdl/rdlc report files without SSRS?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, rdl

Is there any way to render and export an rdl file within a batch process without using SSRS?

I don't want the overhead of SSRS (IIS + database) and instead want to handle this within my own batch/scheduling service.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can conceivably use the [Report Viewer control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671(VS.80).aspx) in a server process written in managed code. You pass the control a data source (which can be a DataTable memory object), and it will return a byte stream that you can direct into a file.

The control has a UI, but that can be by-passed.

Comment: Thanks. I just found this link.
http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2006/03/02/How-to-render-client-report-definition-files-_28002E00_rdlc_2900_-directly-to-the-Response-stream-without-preview.aspx

Comment: How does a ReportViewer render a report? It uses the ReportServer web service on an IIS server. rdlc files are different to rdl files.

Comment: The Report Viewer control does not need a Report Server, and you can simply rename an rdl file to rdlc. The control will ignore certain parts of the rdl file, like the data source that was defined in the report designer. I have deployed rdl files in this way without a problem.

Comment: Version 1.0 was indeed a pain, but it has improved a lot.